Visual Studio Code Workbench Color Customization. How to change color of the activity bar's explorer's list views left border? (See screenshots)
How to change color of the activity bar's explorer's list views left border? (See screenshots)
I tried everything I could and know about
Searched through vscode's color customization documentation page, Checked classes of the panel in Webview developer tools and used color picker to find it's RGB value in default theme JSON file.
How do I customize color of the vertical line at the left of file icons? It's barely visible but maybe I really do have an OCD.
Hovered + selected:

Inactive (only one blackish line):

I tried everything I could and know about

Found the properties which colors those lines.

Ctrl+P

Type: Settings JSON and open the first found item

Add following lines to the JSON file you just opened (Following snippet must be delimited by additional braces.)
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "tree.indentGuidesStroke": "#00000000",
  "tree.inactiveIndentGuidesStroke": "#00000000",

},


#00000000 Sets the color to be fully transparent. You can choose any other color. Search for RGB and RGBA (Red,Green,Bue and Red,Green,Blue,Alpha) color formatting to customize.
